Integer and List<case> from Apex Class are not shown in Aura Component
I've tried everything, I've checked all the questions and answers, but I can't see the error. Can you please tell me why the numbers and cases are not displayed? System logs are output and it feels like everything should be fine. But I still can't see anything.
Apex Class (part). Add I've added only the methods I use in this issue:
public class CasesItems {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Case> getCasesByCriteria(String path, String inbox) {
    List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, Subject, First_lines_of_email__c, Attention__c, Unread_time__c, SuppliedEmail, Unread_Email__c FROM Case WHERE (Path_Status__c = :path AND Inbox__c = :inbox) WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED ];
    return cases;
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Integer countUserCasesByCriteria(Id userId) {
    List<AggregateResult> caseCount = [SELECT COUNT(Id) recordCount FROM Case WHERE 
    (Path_Status__c = 'Reopen' AND OwnerId = :userId) WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
    Integer aggregatedValue = 0;
    if (!caseCount.isEmpty()) {
    // Extract the aggregated value from the AggregateResult
    'recordCount'
    Object aggregateValueObj = caseCount[0].get('recordCount');

    // Check if the aggregated value is not null
    if (aggregateValueObj != null) {
    // Convert the aggregated value to Integer
    aggregatedValue = Integer.valueOf(aggregateValueObj);
        }
    }
    return aggregatedValue;
  }

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Integer countUserCasesByCriteriaWithUnread(Id userId) {
    Integer caseCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Case WHERE (OwnerId = :userId AND 
Unread_Email__c = true) WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
    return caseCount;
}

}
Aura Controller:
    getCurrentUser : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Get the current user's Id
    var currentUserId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
    
    // Set the current user's Id to the component attribute
    component.set("v.currentUserId", currentUserId);
},

   getMyUnread: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Call the Apex method imperatively
    var userId = component.get("currentUserId");
    var action = component.get('c.countUserCasesByCriteriaWithUnread');
    action.setParams({ userId: userId });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            // Set the returned integer value to the component attribute
            component.set('v.myUnread', response.getReturnValue());
            console.log('I get numbers My Unread');
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to retrieve case count');
        }
    });
    console.log('My Unread view clicked');
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

getMyInboxes: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Call the Apex method imperatively
    var userId = component.get("currentUserId");
    var action = component.get('c.countUserCasesByCriteria');
    action.setParams({ userId: userId });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            // Set the returned integer value to the component attribute
            component.set('v.myInboxes', response.getReturnValue());
            console.log('I get numbers My Inbox');
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to retrieve case count');
        }
    });
    console.log('My Inbox view clicked');
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

fetchCasesByCriteria : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getCasesByCriteria");
    action.setParams({
        path: 'New',
        inbox: 'Support'
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.cases", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed to fetch cases");
        }
    });
    console.log('fetchCasesByCriteria view clicked');
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}

And Aura Component:
  <aura:component controller="CasesItems" 
  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId" 
 access="global">
<aura:attribute name="width" type="String" default="SMALL"/>

<aura:attribute name="currentUserId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="500QD00000D2lwJYAR" />
<aura:attribute name="caseId" type="String" />

<aura:attribute name="selectedItem" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="currentInbox" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="currentPath" type="String" />

<aura:attribute name="myUnread" type="Integer" />
<aura:attribute name="myInboxes" type="Integer" />

<aura:attribute name="Support" type="Integer" />

<aura:attribute name="cases" type="List" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getCurrentUser}" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getMyUnread}" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getMyInboxes}" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchCasesByCriteria}" />


<div>
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12">
        <lightning:card>
            <lightning:verticalNavigation selectedItem="{! v.selectedItem }">
                <lightning:verticalNavigationSection label="My Inboxes">
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItemBadge label="My unread" name="unread" 
            badgeCount="{!v.myUnread}" />
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="My inboxes" name="my_inboxes" 
      badgeCount="{!v.myInboxes}" />
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Shared with me" 
       name="shared_with_me" />
                </lightning:verticalNavigationSection>

                <lightning:verticalNavigationSection label="General Inboxes">
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItemBadge label="Support" name="Support" 
       badgeCount="{!v.Support}" />
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Bookings" name="Bookings"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Deviations" name="Deviations"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Claims" name="Claims"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Invoices" name="Invoices"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Billings" name="Billings"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Customs" name="Customs"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Tech Support" name="Tech 
         Support"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="KAM team" name="KAM team"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Purchase" name="Purchase"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Notification" 
      name="Notification"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Errors ONE" name="Errors ONE"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="EDI Invoices" name="EDI 
     Invoices"/>
                    <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="Price changed" name="Price 
    changed"/>
                </lightning:verticalNavigationSection>

            </lightning:verticalNavigation>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
        <lightning:flexipageRegionInfo width="{!v.width}"/>
        <lightning:card>
            <lightning:tabset>
                <lightning:tab label="Unassigned" aura:id="New">
                    <div id="ListViewComp" class="{! v.width}">
                        <!-- Fetch records using force:listView -->
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.cases}" var="case">
                            <p>{!case.Subject}</p>
                            
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </div>
                </lightning:tab>
                <lightning:tab label="Assigned" aura:id="Reopen" />
                <lightning:tab label="Archived" aura:d="In Progress" />
                <lightning:tab label="Snoosed" aura:id="Archived" />
            </lightning:tabset>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
        <forceChatter:publisher context="RECORD" recordId="{!v.recordId}" />
        <forceChatter:feed type="Record" subjectId="{!v.caseId}" feedDesign="DEFAULT"/>
    </div>
</div>

